# laravel Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a function of this

```
function notifyStore($storeId, $notification,$type, $link)
{
    $notify = new App\Store_notification;
    $notify->store_id = $storeId;
    $notify->notification = $notification;
    $notity->link = $link;
    $notify->type = $type;
    $notify->save();
}
```

And in Controller

```
$order = new Store_order;
    $orderArray['user_id'] = $signed['user_id'];
    $orderArray['store_id'] = $store->store_id;
    $orderArray['payment_method'] = $signed['payment_id'];
    $orderArray['address_info'] = $signed['address'];
    $orderArray['invoice_id'] = $signed['invoice_id'];
    $orderArray['order_status'] = 2;
    $orderArray['created_at'] = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $invoice = $order->insertGetId($orderArray);
    notifyStore($store->store_id,"You have a order to review",3,$signed['invoice_id']);
```

But every time I submit order it generates this error. I don't know what's wrong with it. It says error on line 74 and the line 74 is `$notity->link = $link;`. Can anyone please check and tell me what's wrong?

Error

```
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Creating default object from empty value', 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\ABCProject\\app\\Http\\Helper.php', 74, array('storeId' => 1, 'notification' => 'You have a order to review', 'type' => 3, 'link' => '2017-1-6-888-8280', 'notify' => object(Store_notification), 'notity' => object(stdClass))) in Helper.php line 74
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you have the entity named wrong. Look carefully at the line 74 you have

```
$notity->link = $link;
```

You have written `notity` whereas your variable name is `notify`